# Network/Host Byte Order Functions for multiple platforms

Tags: networking, cross-platform, endianness

I am working on a project wehre current `ntohl`, `ntohs`, `htonl` and `htons` are defined as macros in a standard header file that most files include. This causes problems on platforms where these symbols are already defined, for example, winsock2.h declares functions with the same names mentioned above, and causes compile errors, as these declarations get expanded to my macro definition. On Mac OS, I get thousands of compiler warning, as Mac OS defines these macros for you already.

I want to support Windows, Mac OS and Linux, and use the standard OS functions or macros wherever possible, and if they are not decalred, then use my own definition. What is the best way to do this?

I have tried:

```
#if defined WIN32
  #include <winsock2.h>
#endif
```

but this causes compile errors as there are *lots* of function name clashes with my current, large codebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is hardly a mystery:

```
#ifndef ntohl
#define ntohl(x) ...
#endif
```

Then you just have to make sure that all language and system #includes occur before your own, which is standard practice anyway.